# Find the area of a trapezoid inscribed in a semicircumference

Tags: geometry

The trapezoid $ABCD$ is inscribed in the semicurcumference with center $O$, the diameter $AD$ is three times the base $BC$, if the radius is $3$, find the area of the trapezoid $ABCD$.

I made a aproximated drawing.

[image]

**My try**

It's easy to find that $BC=2$, so if i have the height i can apply the formula of the area, but i can't find it.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: tell me how you got BC $=$ 2

Comment: Well, the diameter $AD=6$, and it's 3 times the base BC.

Comment: im sorry i didn't read the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be the radius of a circle, $l$ be the length of a chord in the circle, and $d$ be the distance from the circle's center to the chord. It is easy to verify by drawing a right triangle that
$$d^2 + \frac{l^2}{4}=r^2$$
In your case, you would like to solve for $d$, the height of the trapezoid, where $l=2$, the length of $BC$, and $r=3$, the radius of the circle, are known quantities.

In this case, the right triangle to draw would be $\triangle BOE$, where $E$ is the midpoint of $BC$.

Comment: @Chris BC is parallel to the diameter AD and hence due to symmetry, a line from its midpoint to the center of the circle will be perpendicular to the diameter AD.

Answer (score 0):

The height is $\sqrt{3^2 - 1^2}$

Area $= .5(6+2)\cdot \sqrt8 = 8\sqrt2$

Comment: Why????????????